# PyCharm uses very lax security on macOS

Tags: java, python, macos, security, pycharm

When looking at entitlements on PyCharm CE for macOS, it shows many serious security exceptions. Here are its entitlements:

```
<dict>
        <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-dyld-environment-variables</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-executable-page-protection</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
```

Why does PyCharm uses such lax security? Is it necessary?

I tried to look into [PyCharm's source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/python), and I saw this commit:

> Add macOS notarization script
>
> GitOrigin-RevId: e8779699a5c41df82848b335a3aed82b7550c7eb
>
> VladRassokhin authored and intellij-monorepo-bot committed on Jun 5,
>   2019 commit 631c91bc1a579488452da099b957305502cda2f4

But I couldn't find a clear reason why PyCharm would need these security gaps. Can anyone with knowledge of PyCharm's code can shed light on this?

Comment: Interesting question, but I don't think it belongs on stack overflow

Comment: It does, because it relates to programming. I am asking what in the code justifies these entitlements. In addition, the tool is an IDE, which is widely used and many questions on SO relate to pycharm (it even has its own tag).

Comment: You may be right, I expect you'll get better answers at SuperUser https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5523/what-is-the-difference-between-super-user-and-stack-overflow